# Не удается вывести данные из БД

Tags: c#, mysql

У меня есть табличка в БД:

[image]

Я хочу, чтобы пользователь мог найти по номеру пробы определенное значение в таблице.
Вот реализация:

```cs
string proba = textBox1.Text;
string A = textBox2.Text;
if (A <= 15)
{
    Baza bd = new Baza();
    using (var connection = bd.getConnection())
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT A15 FROM `analiz` WHERE proba=@prob", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prob", proba);
        connection.Open();
        string analiz = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
    }
}
```

По итогу `analiz = null`. Ввожу команду `SELECT A15 FROM 'analiz' WHERE proba = 1` в БД и в итоге получаю 227. При отладке смотрю значение параметра `proba`, этот параметр передается нормально. В других формах у меня такой же код и все корректно выводится.
Что могло пойти не так?

Comment: В базе поле `proba` это строка или число? У вас в программе это строка.

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось простым. В код я добавил еще одну строку

```
string[] analiz1 = analiz.Split(new String[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

В режиме отладки я увидел, что бд передает значение при наведении на эту новую строку. Оказалось, что у меня дальше переменная не передавалась и из-за этого я не мог вывести значение.